# Populate images, script not working properly

Tags: php

I have this piece of code im working with and it does work except one small issue.

When populating the images, there is always one image that doesn't show up on the webserver.

e.g. if I upload 7 different pictures, only 6 of them will show.

It is random which image doesn't display.

This is the code, can anyone see why it is doing this?

```
<?php 
$files = glob("images/".$_GET['user']."/*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++) { 
$num = $files[$i]; 
//print $num; 
echo '<a class="fancybox" href="http://SERVER/'.$num.'"><img border="1" align="middle" width="300" height="200" src="http://SERVER/'.$num.'" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting $i at 1. Try setting $i = 0; inside of your for loop. This may do the trick.

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad I could help!